# How can I use Bengali in an AngularJS script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I have an app that is using Angular.  I am loading a JSON file to display data on the page in different languages.  This works fine with all other languages so far, but I get an error when the variable values are in Bengali. The error is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 38".

I have already ensured that the server response is in UTF-8. If I use naked JavaScript (aka no libraries or frameworks), the JSON object can be parsed with no problem.

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', []);

App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.setLang = function(language) {
        document.getElementById("rootElement").lang = language;

        $http.get('_customizable/languages/' + language + '.js', {header: {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset:utf-8"}})
           .then(function(res){
              $scope.translated = res.data;                
            }
        );
    }
    $scope.setLang(document.getElementById("rootElement").lang);
});
```

**bn.js**

```
{
   "Applications":"অ্যাপ্লিকেশন",
   "AccountSettings": "অ্যাকাউন্ট সেটিংস",
   "AuthorizationManager": "অনুমোদন ম্যানেজার ",
   "DCCMaintenance": "ডিসিসি রক্ষণাবেক্ষণ",
   "MastercardClearing": "মাস্টারকার্ড ক্লিয়ারিং",
   "ParticipantManager": "অংশগ্রহণকারীর ম্যানেজার",
   "PropertiesManager": "বৈশিষ্ট্যাবলী ম্যানেজার",
   "VisaClearing": "ভিসা ক্লিয়ারিং",
   "WorkflowManager": "কর্মপ্রবাহ ম্যানেজার",
   "Users": "ব্যবহারকারী",
   "Groups": "দল",
   "RecordsSearch": "রেকর্ডস অনুসন্ধান",
   "UserName": "ব্যবহারকারীর নাম",
   "Search": "খোঁজো",
   "Reset": "রিসেট",
   "UserRecords": "ব্যবহারকারীর রেকর্ডস",
   "Delete": "মুছে ফেলুন",
   "AllRightsReserved": "সমস্ত অধিকার সংরক্ষিত."
}
```

Note: This even returns an error on several online JSON editors, such as http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: I copy-pasted the thing to the JSON validator URL you provided and it works for me. Maybe open the JSON with a hex editor and check if you don't find anything suspicious.

Comment: Have you included the rule sets of the Bangladesh language (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n + https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/angular-locale_bn-bd.js) maybe this will help somehow

Comment: Also, how do you load the JSON into the app? Using `$http`? Provide some code snippet maybe

Comment: Yes, using $http.get.  I'll edit the question to include more code when I get to the office in the morning.  At the time I didn't think it would be relevant.

Comment: @jakub.g, please see additional code as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So......it took getting a hold of the original file instead of the one pasted in here (benefit of working together) but the problem has been found.

The first clue something was odd is that copying the version posted here into a json validation site worked.

So, when I compared the original file to the one posted here in a hex editor we were able to spot the difference.  When the original English version of the file was dropped into Google Translate to convert to Bengali the 3 leading spaces in front of each line were changed from 0x20 0x20 0x20 to 0xC2 0xA0 0xC2 0xA0 0x20.

So....the moral of the story, don't translate EVERYTHING in your file, just translate the smaller pieces that need translating.